# Run VPN (openconnect) on VPS without breaking SSH

Tags: ubuntu, vpn

I have a VPS server and I want to connect it to a CiscoVPN with openconnect, so traffic from the VPS passes over the VPN, but I also want to be able to use SSH. Right now when I start openconnect the ssh connection drops because its traffic is intercepted and redirected.

Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: did you ever find an answer to this?

Answer (score 1):

Add "-b" arg to openconnect command

```
openconnect server.net -b
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate what does `-b` does and why is it a good solution?

Comment: @styrofoamfly [-b,--background] http://www.infradead.org/openconnect/manual.html I use this method and it works after close ssh session